# Ligatures with Libertine: issue with pdflatex (and Windows)

Tags: ligatures, libertine

If you compile the piece of code given below using pdflatex, then open the resulting PDF file with your preferred viewer, copy the word "efficient" and paste it in a text editor, you will read "efcient". This does not happen with xelatex or lualatex. Is there a way to fix this issue with pdflatex?

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
efficient
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't happen to me. Can you be more precise about your TeX system?

Comment: Do you, by any chance, compile first to dvi?

Comment: I can reproduce this with pdfLaTeX on MikTeX (Win 10).

Comment: @egreg Texlive 16 and Windows 10. Tested pdf viewers: Acrobat Pro and Sumatra pdf.

Comment: @Mico No. I run :>pdflatex myfile.tex

Comment: No problem under Ubuntu 18.04 with TeX Live 2017.

Comment: Does it help to put `\usepackage{cmap}` as line two right after the documentclass?

Comment: Add `\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you please transform your comment into an answer with maybe adequate explanatory details? Thanks

Comment: You mention that you use TeXlive2016. Any chance you could update to TeXlive2018?

Comment: @Mico yes I could but it looks like there is an easier fix, see above.

Comment: @Mico I see the problem also with tl2018. Imho it is (also) viewer (and so OS) dependant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add

```
\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1
```

`glyphtounicode.tex` contains a lot of mappings like

```
\pdfglyphtounicode{ffi}{0066 0066 0069}
```

which are added to the pdf and helps the viewer to correctly interprete special chars. 
I didn't check which of the mappings is needed for libertine, imho it doesn't harm to simply load the whole lot.

The issue itself can be viewer dependant -- some are better in guessing than other.

Comment: Why not simply load cmap, see pdftex-a.pdf, p. 31: »LaTeX users could load the cmap package to achieve the same effect.« ?

Comment: @KeksDose cmap doesn't work for all fonts (and here not with libertine). "The main limitation currently is inability to work with virtual fonts".

Comment: Aha, thank you! I should have had a look into the cmap manual. Which says, by the way, the inablity to work with virtual fonts were a limitation of pdftex. So on the pdftex side this is no longer a limitation?