# Package cmap or `\input glyphtounicode`?

Tags: pdftex, copy-paste

I'm sending PDFs to some folks who are supposed to copy some of the content elsewhere. It is important that my files are searchable and copyable (while I doubt these words to be proper English...)

So I'm using the package cmap. Recently I have been told, that cmap comes with a limitation, and indeed the manual says: »The main limitation currently is inability to work with virtual fonts, and this is because of limitation of pdftex, and may be resolved in a future versions of pdftex.«

In a question about ligatures and the libertine font [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450382/4736) the advice was to use

```
\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1
```

instead of the package cmap.

The [pdftex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/pdftex/manual/pdftex-a.pdf) manual on p. 29 explaines:

> The glyphtounicode.tex file (distributed with pdfTEX and other
>   software) contains thousands of such definitions, covering most common
>   glyph names. ... LaTeX users could load the cmap package to achieve the 
>   same effect.

I can't find any hint to the limitation, which is mentioned by the cmap manual. So my question is:

*Does  `\input glyphtounicode \pdfgentounicode=1`work with virtual fonts? Has the limitation mentioned in the cmap manual been resolved?*

Comment: The `\input glyphtounicode \pdfgentounicode=1` method is newer. It made its way into pdflatex end of 2006. It works with virtual fonts but imho it does *not* work with pk-fonts, only with type1 fonts (no idea about ttf).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So the cited sentence in the pdftex-a manual about LaTeX users may use cmap is wrong?

Comment: Yes, imho it is at least quite misleading. The libertine example shows cleary that the two methods do not do the same.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Could you please help to expand your comment into an answer? Any detail on `glyphtounicode` shall be much valuable.