# Avoid that star symbol is searchable with questionmark "?"

Tags: math-mode, formatting, symbols, pdf

Given the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$a \star b$.
\end{document}
```

This produces the desired output in the PDF file.

However, my problem is that if I search in the PDF file (with CTRL-F) for the questionmark character "?" (without quotation marks), that this specific star symbol is found by the search engine as if it were a questionmark (although it is a star).

This is annoying, because I like to search my final PDF for questionmarks in order to find outdated labels/citations etc. quickly. If there are lots of symbols like \star, that are found as "false positives", this workflow gets tedious and error prone.

**Question**: Is there a way to fix this issue? I want to use symbols like \star in my document but I don't want to find them in the final PDF when searching for questionmarks.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451235 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450382.

Comment: As a side note: Why don't you use LaTeX's warning messages to find undefined references?

Comment: @schtandard Mainly as a double safety check and because the log files can become quite long from warnings that are intentionally ignored (might be because the original template is already shipped like that).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try glyphtounicode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1
\begin{document}
$a \star b$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Is there a reference for `glyphtounicode` somewhere?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner See the pdftex documentation.

Comment: That seems to work, thank you.

Comment: @SampleTime Possible alternative: The `pdftex` manuals states, that the https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cmap package has the same effect (`LATEX users could load the cmap package to achieve the same effect.`). But I think that Ulrike's approach is more general and safer (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451235).